# MIPS Store keyboard input (ints) to array

Tags: mips

I am trying to take 4 numbers from the keyboard and store it to an array. I have come up with the following code however when I try and print the first number in the array it prints 0. Why is it not printing the first value in the array?

```
main: 
li $v0, 5 # read integer 
syscall
add $s0, $v0, $zero #store input1 to s0

li $v0, 5 # read integer 
syscall
add $s1, $v0, $zero #store input2 to s0

li $v0, 5 # read integer 
syscall
add $s2, $v0, $zero #store input3 to s0

li $v0, 5 # read integer 
syscall
add $s3, $v0, $zero #store input4 to s0

.data 
list:   $s0, $s1, $s2, $s3 #set array from keyboard values
.text

#get the array into a register
la $t3, list # put address of list into $t3
lw $t4, 0($t3) # get the value from the array cell

li $v0, 1 # print integer 
move $a0, $t4 # what to print is stored at $s1 
syscall # make system call


exit:    
    li $v0, 10 # exit system call 
syscall
```

Idea taken from:
http://www.cs.pitt.edu/~xujie/cs447/AccessingArray.htm
But they are using hard-coded ints instead of values saved to registers from keyboard.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
.data 
list:   $s0, $s1, $s2, $s3 #set array from keyboard values
.text
```

does not work this way. You need `sw` to store the values of registers to memory.

So, at the start of the program, reserve some space to store the values:

```
.data 
list:  .space 16
.text
```

Then, after you read the values, store them with `sw`:

```
sw $s0, list
sw $s1, list + 4
sw $s2, list + 8
sw $s3, list + 12
```